Add a query label to the BigQuery job information schema when reading from BigQuery or writing from BigQuery in a PySpark notebook on Databricks
I need to add a label/labels to every job that runs in a Databrick PySpark notebook to be able to get a cost overview per Databricks notebook job.
According to the documentation of the Spark BigQuery Connector (https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector?tab=readme-ov-file#tagging-bigquery-resources) one can add a label with the following setting:

The connector can launch BigQuery load and query jobs. Adding labels to the jobs is done in the following manner:

spark.conf.set("bigQueryJobLabel.cost_center", "analytics")
spark.conf.set("bigQueryJobLabel.usage", "nightly_etl")


This will create labels cost_center=analytics and usage=nightly_etl.

This code should add 2 labels, one with key: cost_center, value: analytics and one with key: usage, value: nightly_etl.
If I set those 2 labels I expect them to show up in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT if I understand the documentation correctly with the following code:
select
    creation_time,
    user_email,
    (select unnested_labels.key   from unnest(labels) as unnested_labels) as label_key,
    (select unnested_labels.value from unnest(labels) as unnested_labels) as label_value,
from
    {my_project}.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`

If I run the following code to read from BigQuery in a Databricks notebook I only get NULL for the label keys and label values:
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark.conf.set("temporaryGcsBucket", "company-databricks-bigquery-temp")
spark.conf.set("bigQueryJobLabel.cost_center", "analytics")
materialized_view_tempLocation = "db_tmp_location"

query = f"SELECT id, name FROM `project.dataset.table` where id is not null"
df = (
    spark.read.format("bigquery")
    .option("materializationDataset", materialized_view_tempLocation)
    .option("query", query)
    .load()
)

And I expect the labels as well when I write to BigQuery:
df.write
        .format("bigquery")
        .mode("overwrite")
        .option("project", "project")
        .option("table", "dataset.table")
        .save()
    )

How can I label the jobs done by a Databrick notebook when I read from BigQuery and write to BigQuery so that I can query the label/labels in the {my_project}.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT` table to get a cost overview per job per Databricks notebook?

Do you know which Spark BigQuery connector do you have in your Databricks installation? Can you replace it with the latest one and test again?
